# How to get GitKraken feature working - "Use local SSH agent"

Tags: ssh-keys, gitkraken, multiple-repositories

### In brief

What is the proper way to set SSH keys in GitKraken to work with different git github/bitbucket repos?

### Full details

The feature is snapshot as below in GitKraken preference.
When I check `Use local SSH agent`, git pull/push/... commands stop working. Using git command from console works normally for me.

Currently I have to uncheck it, and select the ssh key I want to use which is quite tiring when working with multiple git repo providers.

My [google search](https://www.google.com.vn/search?q=how%20to%20get%20gitkraken%20use%20local%20ssh%20agent%20working&oq=how%20to%20get%20gitkraken%20use%20local%20ssh%20agent%20working&aqs=chrome..69i57.10423j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and [search on our site](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how%20to%20get%20gitkraken%20use%20local%20ssh%20agent%20working) result litle helpful, so I asked here.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Are you running gitkraken under linux? For me the problem was, that I had to export `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` for gitkraken to find the agent.

So I start gitkraken like this:

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK="$(gpgconf --list-dirs agent-ssh-socket)" /usr/share/gitkraken/gitkraken
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be a rare case, but if it could help at least someone:
For me perosnally, having the same issue after installing gitkraken, it did help to restart the computer after installation. Everything worked then.